# Install a software without user interaction

Tags: 12.04, installation, apt

**Background :**

I have made a shell script to install my software in linux(ubuntu) environment. I have to install few third party software as well.

**Problem :**

Since I run this shell script automatically(this is working properly, no need to think about that), I need to remove the User interaction while installing the third part softwares such as apache2/ php.

**Question :**

Currently I'm using `apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5` something like that. How can I avoid the user interaction(press `y` to continue) while installing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use -qq -y for apt get.

```
apt-get -qq -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 php5
```

-qq = no output, only on errors

-y = answer all questions with yes.

apt-get -h gives you an explanation of all options.

If you like to install software that has interactive function (like mysql, phpmyadmin) etc. and you really want to install them quiet, you can do:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

before the apt-get install command.
But be careful, some software then needs to be configured later. (Like mysql root password, for phpmyadmin you need to link apache.conf to /etc/apache2/conf.d and so on)

Comment: it works, and any idea about `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` ? I saw this one some other place.

Comment: I have extended my answer for that